# Find query on nested json object

Tags: mongodb

I have document structure like:

```
{
      "date": "2017-02-28T13:06:05Z",
      "id": "370adb62d5b1461ead2c4d9410710482",
      "json": {
              "flag": true,
              "key": "abc",
              "no":{ 
                    "no1":"one",
                    "no2":"two"
                   }
               }
}
```

I want to retrive documents where key equals "abc" and no1 equals "one"

Please help !

Comment: Please show us your effort and tell us where you are stuck. So that we can help you out to solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do the trick :

```
db.collection.find({"json.key": "abc", "json.no.no1": "one"})
```

try it online: [mongoplayground.net/p/XelDmKBa6JS](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XelDmKBa6JS)